# T. Isiwata's "T. Isiwata. d-, d*-maps and cb*-spaces."

Tags: gn.general-topology, paper-request

I need T. Isiwata's article T. Isiwata. d-, d*-maps and cb*-spaces. Bull. Tokyo. Gakugei Univ. Ser. IV, 29, 1977.

Does anyone have it?

https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=0454902

https://u-gakugei.repo.nii.ac.jp/records/21841